# $apply does not render ng-repeat if I prepend to array unless I change the browser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sockjs service that $broadcasts an event when it receives a message from the server. In this case, it is receiving the latest news

In my controller I have the following code:

```
$scope.$on("link-created", function(event, data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        var newNews = $.parseJSON(data);
        for(var i=0; i<newNews.length; i++) {        
                $scope.newsLinks.unshift(newNews[i]);  

        }
    });
});
```

Now, the entire list in my view ($scope.newsLinks) is rendered using ng-repeat. When the above code is called in the $apply, the ng-repeat rendering disappears and does not come back unless I re-size the browser. When I re-size the browser, only then does the ng-repeat become visible and look as I expect.

If I change unshift to push (instead of pre-pending I add the object to the end of the array) this problem does not exist. My guess is because the end of the list is not visible on the screen (you have to scroll down).

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this? Can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is my directive code

```
<span  ng-repeat="newsLink in newsLinks" tabindex="{{$index}}"> 
<a href="{{newsLink.link}}" target="_blank" title="{{newsLink.description}}" ng-focus="setSelectedNewsLink($index)" ng-class="(newsLinksSelectedIndex == $index) ? 'selected-news': ''">
[{{newsLink.publishedDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd|HH:mm' }}] - {{newsLink.title}}</a><br> 
</span>
```

Comment: Simplified unshift example works here: http://jsfiddle.net/zv1a0ow1/, are you getting errors on the console at all? Can you show your ng-repeat html and a sample of the `newNews` data?

Comment: Why do you call $apply there? How do you emit/broadcast?

Comment: I added the html code to the edit. I am getting no errors in the console.  I broadcast using: $rootScope.$broadcast("link-created", eventData);

Comment: All, I realized this error is being called by a custom directive I have in a div that acts as a container. The directive is interfering with the rendering. I apologize

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of a conflicting directive I have in my code. I apologize for this and am investigating further to see what specifically in the directive is causing this issue.

Edit:

Right now in my directive it is because I am watching the window height and width. I am still exploring to see if this is the cause.

```
var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return {
                'h': w.height(), 
                'w': w.width()
            };
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {});
```